# Does headjs offer any practical performance benefits over traditional JavaScript approaches?

Tags: javascript, performance, head.js

From the information on the [headjs website](http://headjs.com/), it looks like loading files in parallel using headjs is the fastest way to load external JS files. It also says that loading JS files on the bottom or top of the page doesn’t make a big difference.

It sounds convincing, but I'm afraid that the website is biased.

Which is faster?

- Using headjs
- Packagine / gzipping / minifying / compiler your javascript

Comment: Oh cmon. This question is not subjective. it's "Does headjs offer performance gain over minify/gzip/package/closure". It's a simple numbers / maths question

Comment: i actually just want to hear everybody's opinions on this matter..if all of them think of headjs vs minify/gzip/package/etc as a subjective and argumentative issue, then would it be safe for me to assume that they are pretty much the same (no advantage over another)?

Comment: it was a legit question, you just phrased in an argumentative manner. I fixed that though. It might open again.